# GiveFeedback Event to change Cursor

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop

i have a control which embeds two UserControls those user controls have some sub controls.

For reference:

---

> ```
> **MyControl**      
>
> *User Control 1 (UC1)*
>
>     SubControl UC1-1
>
> *User Control 2 (UC2)*
>
>     SubControl UC2-1          SubControl UC2-2            SubCOntrol UC2-3
> ```

---

Now from UC1-1 i have to Drag an object and Drop it on UC2-2.

For this i have enabled AllowDrop property of UC2  and UC2-2 to true and UC2-1 and UC2-3 to false, so that object cannot be dropped on these controls.

I am using the GiveFeedback event of UC1-1 control to change the cursor.

```
private void grid_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
    Cursor.Current = MyCursor;
}
```

By this the cursor is changed when i drag my mouse over UC2, but it gets changed for all the subcontrols - UC2-1, UC2-2 and UC2-3.

**EDIT :**

To have the Copy Effects I have handled the DragEnter event.

```
private void UC2_2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```

---

What i want is to change the cursor only when it is moved over UC2-2 and not on UC2-1 and UC2-3.

Comment: You need to do this in the DragEnter event handler inside UC2-2.  It should only set e.Effect if you are happy about the object that's being dragged.  You may need to create a little helper class that stores the drag object so you can positively identify it as the object that came from UC1-1.

Comment: I have set the 'e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;' for my UC2-2 only. And yes I have the class that identifies the Dragged object as valid object.

Comment: No idea what you are trying to say.  Post your DragEnter event handler code.

Comment: I have handled this event only for UC2-2. I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Well, sure, that can't work.  You *must* check that the expected object is being dragged before you set e.Effect.  Use at least e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(yourDragClass))

Comment: Well i have used e.Data.GetDataPresent() in DragDrop event. I am pretty sure about Dragged Object.

Comment: It must be present in the DragEnter event.  The only way to get the "you can't drop here" cursor.

Comment: If i am not wrong, than this method will only tell that the dragged object has the data of my Type or not. How can i get "you can't drop here" cursor on the basis of this?

Comment: You are not limited to GetDataPresent().  You can also call e.Data.GetData(typeof(yourDragClass)) to get a reference to the object.  And check its properties to make sure you are happy about it.

Comment: OK...i believe that i will always be happy with the object that is being dragged. What i am not happy is it getting dragged to somewhere else. i hope you are getting my point.

Comment: I dont want to know where the object came from, i want to know where the object is going to. I dont think that i am quite clear.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support.Finally i got the solution of my own, i have to just set the AllowDrop property of MyControl to False and just keep the AllowDrop property for UC2-2 to true. It worked like charm. :)